# multiple back to back boost::asio async_send_to calls cause buffer overun

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I am having a problem with sending multiple back to back separate UDP buffers using boost asio.  I have a 1 second asio timer that fires a callback that transmits a 2 separate UDP datagram structures over udp.  Each of the these messages structures is allocated via std::unique_ptr, so they should not go out of scope by the time the async CADaemon::handle_send callback is called.

```
void
CADaemon::heartBeatTimer(
    const milliseconds& rHeartBeatMs)
{
    mpStatusTimer->expires_from_now(rHeartBeatMs);
    mpStatusTimer->async_wait(boost::bind(
        &CADaemon::heartBeatTimer,
        this, rHeartBeatMs));
    if (mpALBFSocket && mpALBFEndpoint) {
        mpALBFSocket->async_send_to(
            buffer(mpStatusMessage.get(),
                sizeof(MemberSystemStatusMessage)),
            *mpALBFEndpoint,
            boost::bind(&CADaemon::handle_send, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));


        // must insert delay to prevent buffer overwrites
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10);

        // heartbeat messages are also sent to this socket/endpoint
        mpALBFSocket->async_send_to(
            buffer(mpHeartbeatMessage.get(),
                sizeof(CAServiceHeartbeatMessage)),
            *mpALBFEndpoint,
            boost::bind(&CADaemon::handle_send, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

The receiving application works if I put a small delay in between sending the first message and the second message, however, if I send them as they are, it appears that the second buffer overwrites the first by the time it arrives in the receiving application.

What am I doing incorrectly?

I also tried sending multiple buffers with the code below, however that behaves worse as it coalesces both datagrams as a single long datagram.

```
void
CADaemon::heartBeatTimer(
    const milliseconds& rHeartBeatMs)
{
    mpStatusTimer->expires_from_now(rHeartBeatMs);
    mpStatusTimer->async_wait(boost::bind(
        &CADaemon::heartBeatTimer,
        this, rHeartBeatMs));
    if (mpALBFSocket && mpALBFEndpoint) {
        std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> transmitBuffers;
        transmitBuffers.push_back(buffer(
            mpStatusMessage.get(), 
            sizeof(MemberSystemStatusMessage)));
        //transmitBuffers.push_back(buffer(
        //    mpHeartbeatMessage.get(), 
        //    sizeof(CAServiceHeartbeatMessage)));
        mpALBFSocket->async_send_to(
            transmitBuffers, *mpALBFEndpoint,
            boost::bind(&CADaemon::handle_send, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

Here are the Members of the class that are involved in the ASIO from the associated header file.

```
// this message is transmitted @1HZ
std::unique_ptr<MemberSystemStatusMessage> mpStatusMessage;
// this message is transmitted @1HZ
std::unique_ptr<CAServiceHeartbeatMessage> mpHeartbeatMessage;
// this message is received @1HZ
std::unique_ptr<WOperationalSupportMessage> mpOpSupportMessage;
// this message is received @1HZ when valid
std::unique_ptr<MaintenanceOTPMessage> mpOTPMessage;

std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> mpIOService;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> mpALBFSocket;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint> mpALBFEndpoint;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> mpServerSocket;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint> mpServerEndpoint;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::steady_timer> mpStatusTimer;
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> mpReceiveBuffer;
```

This is the callback handler

```
void
CADaemon::handle_send(
    const boost::system::error_code& error,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    static auto& gEvtLog = gpLogger->getLoggerRef(
        Logger::LogDest::EventLog);
    if (!error || (error == boost::asio::error::message_size)) {
        // Critical Section - exclusive write
        boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(gRWMutexGuard);
        LOG_EVT_INFO(gEvtLog) << *mpStatusMessage;
        LOG_EVT_INFO(gEvtLog) << *mpHeartbeatMessage;
        LOG_EVT_INFO(gEvtLog) << "Sent " << bytes_transferred << " bytes";
        mpStatusMessage->incrementSequenceCounter();
    } else {
        LOG_EVT_ERROR(gEvtLog) << "handle_send: asio error code["
            << error.value() << "]";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:ADDED THE RECEIVING JAVA APPLICATION CODE WITH THE BUFFER CORRUPTION**

The code below shows the code in the receiving java application, noted that the sizeof the received datagram is never corrupted, just the contents, the size seems to always be that of the longer datagram.  Hope this is useful to help track down the problem.

```
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                updateMessage("Running...");
                try {
                    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(mPortNum);
                    // allocate space for received datagrams
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length);                    
                    while (!isCancelled()) {                    
                        serverSocket.receive(packet);
                        int bytesReceived = packet.getLength();
                        MemberSystemStatusMessage statusMessage = 
                            new MemberSystemStatusMessage();
                        int statusMessageSize = statusMessage.size();
                        CAServiceHeartbeatMessage heartbeatMessage = 
                            new CAServiceHeartbeatMessage();
                        int heartbeatMessageSize = heartbeatMessage.size();
                        if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
                            if (bytesReceived == statusMessage.size()) {
                                statusMessage.setByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes), 0);
                                setMemberSystemMessage(statusMessage);
                            } else if (bytesReceived == heartbeatMessage.size()){
                                heartbeatMessage.setByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes), 0);
                                setHeartbeatMessage(heartbeatMessage);
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("unexpected datagram");
                            }
                        } else { // update later in FxApplicationThread
                            if (bytesReceived == statusMessage.size()) {
                                statusMessage.setByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes), 0);
                                Platform.runLater(() -> setMemberSystemMessage(statusMessage));
                            } else if (bytesReceived == heartbeatMessage.size()){
                                heartbeatMessage.setByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes), 0);
                                Platform.runLater(() -> setHeartbeatMessage(heartbeatMessage));
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("unexpected datagram");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
                updateMessage("Cancelled");
                return null;
            } 
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks fine as long as the size of the buffers are correct and the underlying memory for the buffers remains valid until the handler is called.  One can safely initiate multiple non-composed asynchronous operations, such as [`async_send_to()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_raw_socket/async_send_to/overload2.html), for a given I/O object.  Albeit, it is unspecified as to the order in which these operations will execute.

The receiver application has a single shared byte array into which datagrams are read.  If two datagrams are received, and two read operations occur, then the buffer will contain the contents of the last read datagram.  Based on the presented code, this can create a race condition due to the `Runnable`s that will be invoked at an unspecified time in the future.  For example, consider the scenario where two datagrams are sent, the first containing a system message and the second containing a heartbeat message.  In the following code:

```java
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length);
while (...)
{
  serverSocket.receive(packet);
  int bytesReceived = packet.getLength();
  MemberSystemStatusMessage statusMessage =  ...;
  CAServiceHeartbeatMessage heartbeatMessage =  ...;
  if (bytesReceived == statusMessage.size())
  {
    statusMessage.setByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes), 0);
    Platform.runLater(() -> setMemberSystemMessage(statusMessage));
  }
  ...
}
```

After the first iteration of the while-loop, `bytes` contains a status message and the `statusMessage` object refers to the `bytes` buffer.  A Runnable has been scheduled to run at an unspecified time in the future.  Upon reading the second datagram, the `bytes` buffer contains a heartbeat message.  The Runnable now runs, passing the `statusMessage` object to `setMemberSystemMessage()`; however, its underlying buffer now contains a heartbeat message.  To resolve this problem, consider deep-copying the byte array when deferred execution needs to occur:

```
if (bytesReceived == statusMessage.size())
{
  byte[] bytes_copy = Arrays.copyOf(bytes, bytesReceived);
  statusMessage.setByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes_copy), 0);
  Platform.runLater(() -> setMemberSystemMessage(statusMessage));
}
```

Alternatively, one could use a new buffer for each read operation.

There may also be problems with expectations of the underlying protocol.  UDP is referred to as an unreliable protocol as it does not provide notifications to the sender as to the delivery of the datagram.  Each `async_send_to()` operation will result in up to one datagram being transmitted.  The completion handler's status indicates if the data was written, and implies no status on if if the datagram has been received.   This holds true even if multiple buffers are provided via [scatter-gather I/O](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffers_and_scatter_gather_i_o).  As such, the scenario described in the question, where two `async_send_to()` operations are initiated, but the recipient only receives a single datagram, is permitted by the protocol.  The application protocol should account for this behavior.  For instance, instead of reporting an error after a single heartbeat deadline has been missed, the recipient may report an error once a consecutive number of missed heartbeat deadlines have exceeded a threshold.  Adding a small delay between writes provides no guarantees as to the behavior of the protocol.

Comment: If Boost.Asio is going to match the TR2 proposal, then the order seems to be specified. I agree that the protocol is permitted to drop packets, However, in this case, a bug in the receiving application is also possible/likely.

Comment: @TannerSansbury thanks for persisting and finding that the problem was in fact the client, well done!

Comment: @TannerSansbury I wonder if you could look at a follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626870/java-nio-datagramchannel-corruption - I changed my java code to use NIO and I never really understood why I had to quickly copy the bytes before the next message corrupted the existing receive buffer bytes.  I thought that given a sufficiently large enough receive buffer that the next write to the receive buffer would not corrupt the previous buffer

Comment: @johnco3 The original code had a single buffer and each datagram was read into the start of the buffer (e.g. `bytes[0]`).  The size of the buffer does not affect this behavior.  The buffer does not behave as a stream (e.g. read into the buffer at the end of the previously read data).

Answer (score 1):

Update:

As mentioned by Tanner Sansbury, this answer is likely wrong. I'm leaving it here for people searching for an answer to the question of whether it is valid to have multiple calls to `async_send_to` outstanding concurrently. The answer seems to be "yes".

Original:

The problem with this code is that the second call to `async_send_to()` does not wait for the first one to complete. You should make the second call to `async_send_to()` from the first completion handler, assuming no errors.

The coalescing of the two buffers into one datagram in your second example is expected behaviour.

Comment: One can safely initiate multiple `async_send_to()` operations on a single socket while there are pending `async_send_to()` operations on the same socket ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f29db29ad346031e)).

Comment: @TannerSansbury nice demo, however I thought that it was not valid to do what I was doing (which you also do in the demo) which is send multiple async writes one after the other without waiting for each to be received first.  I did something similar to you - it appeared to work but the buffers were corrupted when I examined them, I will try your demo on Windows to see if it acts the same (I'll need to modify the buffer contents as they are not being checked in your demo).  My results were via Visual Studio 2015 with Boost v1.60

Comment: @TannerSansbury Interesting. The demo might work on your platform but does not prove the API behaviour across platforms. I've just spent a bit of time trying to establish the nature of the API promise; my answer could well be wrong. The only statement I found so far is here http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/5403 which says "Remember that if you are using async_send_to() you can not call it again on the same socket until the first async_send_to() was signalled as completed." This is consistent with my usage of ASIO. I'll take a quick look at the implementation ...

Comment: @TannerSansbury A look at the TR2 network library proposal contains the following statement for asynchronous socket operations "When there are multiple outstanding asynchronous write operations on s, the buffers are transmitted in the order in which these operations were issued. The order of invocation of the completion handlers for these operations is unspecified.", and the code in Boost.Asio 1.60 seems to also support that. I don't know if it changed in a prior version of ASIO, or whether I've just been mistaken for a long time.

Comment: @johnco3 If Tanner is right (and it appears he is), then the problem is likely to be in your receiving application.

Comment: @janm In general, the Asio documentation notes explicit restrictions rather than supported use cases.  For example, Asio's documentation does not explicitly document that one can have an `async_read` and an `async_write` operation pending at the same time, but it does note that while an `async_read` is pending, other read operations should not be initiated.  I rarely use this feature, but as far as I know, it has been supported since Boost.Asio 1.35 for non-I/O completion port demultiplexers and Boost.Asio 1.42.0 for I/O completion port.

Comment: @TannerSansbury Yes, in general that's true. However it has not always (in my experience) listed all the explicit restrictions, hence occasional discovery exercises like this. I note that revision 6 of the Networking Library proposal does explicitly state that multiple asynchronous operations are permitted, where, as you note, the Boost.Asio leaves implicit that `async_read` and `async_write` operations are permitted concurrently (a feature that I use frequently). In any case, I was wrong on `async_send_to`; this will lead to some code revision here and there.

Comment: @janm That has been my experience too.  I am looking forward to having all the features become well defined and described in detail within the [Networking TS](https://github.com/cplusplus/networking-ts).

Comment: @janm I'm confused, so is it correct behavior to put 2 async_send_to calls one after the other without having the handler get called in between these calls?  I noted that you thought that the receiving app might be at fault, I posted it and as far as I can tell it works as expected, note that the datagrams are between localhost and localhost - I have not had a chance to test when it is actually transmitted to a remote PC (where I could use wireskark to verify the buffer corruption)

Comment: @TannerSansbury I tried making your demo work on windows, and I get an error WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL 10049 when attempting to bind the sockets back to back to each other.  in the line socket1.connect(socket2.local_endpoint()); Any ideas?  I'd love to get that app working to verify the behavior locally on windows